# Rolify undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I'm having trouble to install Rolify. I just want to have a Role "Admin", on which when users have it, are able to delete photos.

I have followed the installation process, and everything looks fine, except when I try to add a role to a specific user, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_or_create_by' for #<Rolify::Adapter::ResourceAdapter:0x00000109403710>
```

**User model**

```
  rolify :role_cname => 'Admin'

  resourcify
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Rails do you have?

Comment: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/102

Comment: I've read that a couple of times but still wont work. :(

Answer (score 1):

Delete the 'resourcify' line from your model, as you cant use both rolify and resourcify together.